# How to deal with different numbers of days in a month for comparison?

Tags: paired-data, test-for-trend

My question is very basic, and I'm looking for a conceptual answer.

We put about 55000 values (individual deliveries) on a graph. They are sorted by day of the month to see if there's a trend and to allocate ressources correspondingly.

The result  looks like this.
[image: deliveries by day]

Obviously, the fact that some month have 28/29/30 or 31 days completely skew the analysis at month end.

So far I thought of

- omiting any value happening after a 28th,
- use an average of all last days and put it backward on the 28th,
- "spread" the end of month values onto the whole month,
- trending the last missing day(s) for shorter months and put them all on 31 days

What the "proper way" to deal with it (the way a professionnal statistician would)?

PS: I may lack the vocabulary to search for it in Cross validated SE. Please let me know if it has been already answered.

Comment: There are, quite frankly, any number of ways to answer this question. I think you're going to have to add more context around it. What is this analysis for? For instance, if you switch from a Gregorian calendar with it's unequal days of the month to a Julian calendar, you could kind of *normalize* the days into equally sized, 30 day buckets. Of course, that would then not align with the Gregorian calendar months. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @mike hunter I'm trying  to see if there's a trend in the number of deliveries according to the day of the month (we did the same exercice by the hour,  by weekday and by month and they were discernable trends for that). Basically, because we're a Wednesday  of June at 14:30 I can predict a certain level of deliveries at x% confidence. Is the fact that we're at the begining of the month (or the middle, or the end) can help me predict today's amount ? So to do that, I'm trying to compare apple to apple (end of Feb vs end of March for example)

Comment: You don't say whether or not you have a time series model. Hopefully, you do and your predictions are based on that. If so, you really shouldn't be comparing June days with July, much less December days, when the holiday season and weather conditions could be so totally different. Rather, to keep apples with apples, compare Wednesday, June 10th at 14:30 with a year ago, or two years ago, or whatever the comparison is.